# MultiSubnetFailover does not work with ODBC13/17 in Windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In Windows whether ODBC version 13/17 will work with MultiSubnetFailover keyword and in multisubnet cluster environment ?

Using ODBC13/17 in Windows, after failover, it fails to reconnect to the primary node and gives error as

> Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]The connection is
>   broken and recovery is not possible. The client driver attempted to
>   recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed.
>   Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase the number of
>   recovery attempts

I use SQL server 2016 and 2 nodes in a different subnet.

My connection string looks like

```
"Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server="170.25.132.24";DB="test";USER="abc";PW="XXX";MultiSubnetFailover=No"
```

What is the expected result when we set `MultiSubnetFailover=No` ? Is it recommended to set `MultiSubnetFailover=No` in `multisubnet` cluster environment ?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no benefit from setting `MultiSubnetFailover=No`

Microsoft states:

> We recommend this setting for both single and multi-subnet connections
>   to availability groups listeners and to SQL Server Failover Cluster
>   Instance names. Enabling this option adds additional optimizations,
>   even for single-subnet scenarios.

[Listeners, Client Connectivity, Application Failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#SupportAgMultiSubnetFailover)

The Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is failover cluster capable:

[ODBC Driver on Linux and macOS Support for High Availability and Disaster Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/odbc-driver-on-linux-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-2017)

You need to specify **MultiSubnetFailover=Yes** in your connection string, and 
you should specify the availability group **listener** of the availability group as the server in your connection string.

If you are using Windows, I would suggest using the SQL Server native client: 
[SQL Server Native Client Support for High Availability, Disaster Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/sql-server-native-client-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes, I agree. In Linux, both 13 and 17 works fine.
But in Windows it's not working as expected. I have given AG listener and MultiSubnetFailover=Yes
Also, What is the expected result when we set MultiSubnetFailover=No ?

Comment: Keeping MultiSubnetFailover=Yes has an advantage. But I want to know the behavior when it is set to No. In some cases, I can able to reconnect after failover even it is set to No, but it takes more time to reconnect. But in some cases, it fails to reconnect and keeps on retry. I cannot conclude which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the connection timeout to 60 seconds say? : Connect Timeout=60;

Comment: No, I have not. I have left the application to try re-connect for more than an hour. But still, it does not reconnect. I think MultiSubnetFailover=No can lead to undefined behaviour.